# Find and Remove VB

Tags: vb.net, string

I am trying to be able to find a delete a specific String.

> ```
>     If nameList1.Text.IndexOf(TextBox1.Text) Then
>         nameList1.Text = nameList1.Text + nameList1.Text.Remove(start, theEnd)
>     End If
> ```

I have start and end set to a value the user inputs, would anyone mind helping out?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
substring(start, length)
```

or you can use replace

```
bigString.replace(littleString, "")
```

I'm sure Google, or searching stack overflow could have answered your question faster.

Comment: I am new to this, so what is the syntax for replace, and how does it work.

Comment: @Jerryg225, Adam showed you the syntax. How it works should be obvious if you try the code yourself and experiment with a few different strings and substrings.

Comment: Well yeah, I feel stupid for asking the syntax, but is the first half of the parameter a variable?

Comment: if you are using the Visual Studio IDE, type bigString.replace( and press F1 while the cursor is in "replace" should give you basic syntax help.